# Why do I have unresolved imports in PyCharm for installed dependencies?

Tags: django, import, pycharm

In requirements.pip I have django installed, and the django app works fine. However in the IDE, some django imports are underlined in red and the reported error is that there is an unresolved import.

edit:
My virtualenv is called xx__xx.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can’t have underscore (‘_’) in your virtualenv name.
https://plus.google.com/+MattWoodward/posts/DdFduvCKJP2 (It says hyphens aren’t allowed in the link - I think the same applies for underscores based on my local experiments)